# Message forwarding with doesNotUnderstand in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I had a query about redefining the message `doesNotUnderstand:` in smalltalk. What I want to do is to forward all the messages received by an object that are not understood, to another object that it has in its knowledge. My problem comes from the fact that both objects (both the receiver and the one that forwards) have the same protocol inherited by the super class and when the message is not understood by the specific protocol of the object but if it is understood by the inherited protocol, it executes the message inherited and not the `doesNotUnderstand:` (so the message is not forwarded and the super class message is invoked).

I really appreciate the help, regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a situation in which you want to forward a message but it is understood by the one that forwards (we call that a *proxy* object) so `doesNotUnderstand:` is not being invoked in the proxy.

You have two possible solutions. First (and in general), a proxy object should inherit from `ProtoObject` so as to avoid inheriting any default behavior. But if this is not a true proxy object (that passes along essentially everything), then you need to override the messages that should be forwarded and call `doesNotUnderstand:` (or your forwarding code) directly.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me.


What I was doing was a decorator pattern design, where I wanted that if the wrapper object did not understand a message from its own context (regardless of inherited messages), it would forward the message to the wrapped object and it would define whether or not it could resolve it .
In the end I used forwarding directly as you mentioned, reimplemented the messages I needed to forward from the wrapper.


A greeting!

Comment: Reimplementing doesNotUnderstand: is interesting but dangerous.
Question: Why do you not just implement the messages you dont understand and delegate them to the objects you know they understand?

Comment: If you know what messages will be sent, then you can implement only those messages. If you don't know what messages will be sent, then you use doesNotUnderstand:.